# How to rollback the appcfg in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=ethereal-zodiac-803&version=1&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user suganya.karthik is already in progress for app: s~ethereal-zodiac-803, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".

See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=ethereal-zodiac-803&version=1&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user suganya.karthik is already in progress for app: s~ethereal-zodiac-803, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".

Comment: How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just as the message says, you need to use `rollback` command to undo the previous update that failed to complete. Just replace the word `update` with the word `rollback` (everything else stays the same) and run the command.

You can run it in the terminal window (command prompt) on your computer by running appcfg program.

- Python:
  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp
- Java: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

Comment: I am asking how to use that rollback command and where to use? Where is that command? Sorry I'm new to google app engine.

Comment: I am using Android studio with a google app engine backend. In my case I also had to remove these oauth lines:
--oauth2 --oauth2_client_secret=***** --oauth2_client_id=***** --oauth2_refresh_token=*****

Answer (score 9):

If you are using maven, you can use [rollback](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#app_engine_maven_plugin_goals) goal:

```
mvn appengine:rollback
```

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal:

```
appcfg.py rollback (filename).yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

**In java, windows and eclipse:**

Check the path for you **appengine-java-sdk**, in my case, it look like some things as.

```
 C:\Users\camno\.p2\pool\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.30\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30\bin
```

Now in the console, go to the location of sdk, by type:

```
 cd [your appengine-java-sdk path]
```

Next, you can type the command for rollback:

```
appcfg -e [your_mail_to_deploy@any.com] rollback [path to war of proyect]
```

The characteres [ ] must be no include. You can find more info about the comman arguments in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appcfg-arguments

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine Config Rollback command helped in Resolving the issue.

```
$ appcfg.sh rollback <war location>
```

The above command will prompt for a code. For this code, it will give you a weblink. Go to the link, get the passcode and enter it at the prompt.

For Full command see below (will help you to find appcfg.sh location)

```
$ /home/myuser/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.27/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27/bin/appcfg.sh rollback /home/myuser/workspace/MyProject/war/
```

Answer (score 1):

In MAC os `appcfg.py rollback`

Example:

```
$ appcfg.py rollback workspace/api-asia01/
09:38 AM Application: api-asia01
09:38 AM Host: appengine.google.com
09:38 AM Rolling back the update.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `appcfg.py rollback <app path>`

`<app path>` is the location of your app on your file system

Answer (score 0):

If anyone who has this issue is using Android Studio or Intellij, you can go to your Gradle/Maven tasks, click backend. and click Tasks, click google app engine, and click Rollback. instead of messing with the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

for rollbacking a failed deployment

1. Navigate to the appengine/bin folder in eclipse/contents/plugins/com.google.eclipse.sdkbundle/bin (or) {wherever you have the app engine files}/bin
2. chmod 755 run_java.sh
3. chmod 755 appcfg.sh
4. ./appcfg.sh rollback {location of the app}/war